# Using TypeScript with Node.js, how do I convert an 'import' statement into a 'require' statement?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have the following line of code:

```
import { transliterate as tr, slugify } from 'transliteration';
```

Which is producing an error because I don't have a declaration file.

How can I convert it into a 'require' statement?

Comment: `const { slugify, transliterate: tr } = require('…')`?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/andyhu/transliteration

Comment: It's giving you an *error* or just a warning? What does the error say exactly. Li357's comment is correct